Issue adding Immutable SDK to Unity game with Firebase and AdMob
I'm trying to add the Immutable SDK to my Unity game, which already has Firebase Database and AdMob integrated. However, I'm encountering several issues:
The Immutable SDK requires me to add implementation('androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0') to the mainTemplate.gradle file.
When I open mainTemplate.gradle, the Force Resolve doesn't load the plugins, causing my game to not work.
If I close mainTemplate.gradle, Force Resolve works fine, but then androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0 isn't added.
When I try to manually add androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0 to build.gradle using a script (without opening mainTemplate.gradle), I get an error because there's already a androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0 version present.
Every time I use Force Resolve, it keeps reverting to androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0.
I've tried various approaches but can't seem to resolve this issue. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Additional context:
Unity version: [2022.3.45f1]
Expected behavior:
Successfully integrate Immutable SDK without breaking existing Firebase and AdMob functionality.
Have androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0 correctly added to the project.
Actual behavior:
Unable to add androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0 without causing conflicts or build errors.
